# Cover spans with a transparent div / image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

I want to make the contents of a content-editable div non-editable. 
Let's say I have a structure like:

```
<div contenteditable=true></div>
```

Now with some functionality the the structure will become

```
    <div contenteditable=true> <p class="x">abc</p> some text <p
 class="x">abc</p><p class="x">abc</p><p class="x">abc</p>  again
 editable continues</div>
```

I want to make the div partially non-editable (starting form first `<p>` tag to last `<p>` tag, so I decided to cover them with a transparent div. This works fine if the `<p>` tags are in continuation but if there is some text in between them, it is editable (it is not covered by transparent div).

Is there any solution to cover some content of content editable div with transparent div 
or to make it partially non-editable?

**Note:** I don't want to wrap all `<p>` tags with any other element.

Comment: Why not simply use input fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can do opposite - set div `contenteditable=false` and wrap editable area in span with `contenteditable=true`

Comment: i dont want to do something like this ..... i want to cover some portion of content editable div with a transparent image